# How do you determine if a function is nonelementary antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration

Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral)

> In mathematics, a nonelementary antiderivative is an antiderivative
>   for which it can be shown that there exists no formula in terms of
>   elementary functions

My question is regarding the phrase `can be shown that`. How can it be shown that a function is a nonelementary integrable?

Comment: Maybe this [article][1] is helpful. [1]:http://www.claymath.org/programs/outreach/academy/LectureNotes05/Conrad.pdf

Comment: I believe you're looking for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm